# Loop over __all__ in __init__.py

Tags: python

I have a `__init__.py` file in a folder. This is the content:

```
from .user import UserManager
from .user_group import UserGroupManager

__all__ = [
    "UserManager",
    "UserGroupManager",
]
```

In fact the list of managers is way larger, but that will only make the question to complex. Now I want to loop over all the managers I got. Is there a way to loop over those with this `__init__.py` file? I don't have a list of all possible managers anywhere else in the application, only in this init file.

I thought doing something like this in a `service.py` file:

```
def get_manager_by_id(id: str):
    for manager in managers.__all__:
        # use the manager
```

But that raises an error that manager is a string, which is logic.
Is the solution here to find the manager with the string or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Consider a simpler version of the question. You already have the string that names the *attribute* of the module object that you want to get, and you want to get the corresponding attribute. What happens if you try looking for a solution for that? Like, say, putting `get attribute by string name python` into a search engine?

Comment: Unrelated to this question, I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsHMHukIlJY in which it is explained very well why "Manager" is bad for naming. Probably you could name your classess just `User` and `Group`. Then `managers` are really `modules`.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasonably sensible ways to do this. My preference would go to:

```
# __init__.py
from .user import UserManager
from .user_group import UserGroupManager

MANAGERS = [UserManager, UserGroupManager]

__all__ = [
    "UserManager",
    "UserGroupManager",
]

# service.py
def get_manager_by_id(id: str):
    for manager in managers.MANAGERS:
        # use the manager
```

It has the advantage that if you want to add other things to `__init__.py` (utility functions, constants, classes that aren't managers...), it won't interfere with `get_manager_by_id`.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
# __init__.py remains as you wrote it

# service.py
def get_manager_by_id(id: str):
    for manager_name in managers.__all__:
        manager = getattr(managers, manager_name)
        # use the manager
```

... but if you want to add other things to your package, now you gotta check if `manager` actually is a manager class somehow.